# isPrototypeOf in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am a beginner to ***JavaScript*** and on my way to ***Prototypes in JavaScript***.
As per the article [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp)

**Creating a Prototype**
The standard way to create an object prototype is to use an object constructor function:

```
function person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
}
```

With a constructor function, you can use the new keyword to create new objects from the same prototype:

```
var myFather = new person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
var myMother = new person("Sally", "Rally", 48, "green");
```

***The constructor function is the prototype for your person objects.***
I find myself confused at the above bold line, which I think is absolutely wrong.

**Reason:**

```
alert(person.isPrototypeOf(myFather));  // false
```

Am I correct to say this as I do believe in this line:

> The ‘prototype’ property points to the object that will be assigned as the prototype 
>       of instances created with that function when using ‘new’.

Comment: you don't use prototype at all so in your case this should be true, `myFather instanceof person`

Comment: my 2cents http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Yes, that is line **is** absolutely **wrong**.

Comment: @mfreitas: Your link says W3Schools offers a decent learning experience for beginners.

Comment: @sixfingeredman indeed it does, it also says W3Schools still has issues. These issues have been misleading people for a while now.

Comment: @mfreitas: All such sites have issues. MDN does too, and because it's a wiki, it can and does introduce new issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would agree that terminology is incorrect.

The constructor function has a `prototype` property which defines the properties and methods in the prototype chain; but it is not itself the prototype of an object, it is the constructor.

[`isPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf) is not called on the constructor itself, but on the constructor's prototype property.

```
alert(person.prototype.isPrototypeOf(myFather)); // true
```

`myFather` would be an [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) `person`, and you can test this using the following line.

```
alert(myFather instanceof person); // true
```

Comment: plus one, isPrototypeOf is not called on the constructor itself, but on the constructor's prototype property. A nice line you added that helped me.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with you - the sentence "**The constructor function is the prototype for your person objects**" is confusing and inaccurate. Instead, your understanding is correct although let me elaborate more.

Basically, whenever you create a function in JavaScript, it will automatically have a property on it called `.prototype` and the value associated with it will be an object. In your case, the `person` function also has this `.prototype` property. When you create new instances of `person`, each instance will be set up as inheriting from the object associated with the `person` function's `.prototype` property - the instance's prototype. This inheritance means that property look-ups are **delegated** to this prototype object. The key here is that when your `person` instances look up a property, they will first look up the property on themselves, and if the property isn't found, they will go up the prototype chain.

Looking at your example, here is what is correct:

```
person.prototype.isPrototypeOf( new person() );
```

In other words, any instance of person knows to **delegate** to the object associated with `person.prototype` whenever the instance can't find a property on itself.

Comment: The way you formulated it sounds as if the prototype chain knew the constructors and did follow their `.prototype` properties. Can you fix this, please?

Comment: @Bergi not sure what you mean - maybe its just the way I'm phrasing something? Can you suggest anything to improve what I've written?

Comment: The delegation of a property doesn't go to the object that is referenced by `person`s `.prototype` property. Yes, it is the same object, but the delegation process doesn't know about `person` - only the prototype object it inherits from. I've tried to rephrase your ansewer, please rollback when you don't like it.

Answer (score 3):

What you are saying,

> The ‘prototype’ property points to the object that will be assigned as the prototype of instances created with that function when using ‘new’.

Doesn't make much sense to me, but I think you've got the right idea.

To me, at least,
***The constructor function is the prototype for your person objects.***
is wrong.

The correct version would be:
***The constructor function is the constructor function for your person objects.***

---

The prototype property of your constructor function is an object.

It contains properties which are assigned to objects instantiated with that constructor function, example:

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype = {
    species: "Human"
};
```

Sets up a constructor function with a prototype property, containing a property `species`.

Now, if we do this:

```
var joe = new Person("Joe");
```

joe is an object which looks like

```
{
    name:    "Joe",
    species: "Human"
}
```

As you can see, the properties of the prototype of `Person()` were set as normal properties of Joe.

## TL;DR

So I think you had the right idea.

Comment: No! The properties on the prototype are **not** "assigned" to the instances. `joe` does not have an (own) `species` property, it does not "look like" that.

Comment: I agree with @Bergi, the `joe` object doesn't look like that. It will look like this: `{ name: 'Joe' }` with the additional caveat that there will be a __prototype__ property which points to the `prototype` object.

Comment: @wmok no, try it in your js console. `joe.species` exists, `joe.prototype` doesn't.

Comment: @minseong: You are looking for `Object.hasOwnProperty(joe, "species")` (false) and `Object.getPrototypeOf(joe)` (the prototype chain property)