# .isPrototypeOf() and .hasOwnProperty() method confusion

Tags: javascript

Let say i have this code:

```js
// Male will inherit ALL of the Human properties
function Human(x, y) {
  // Following properties will be inherited
  this.name = x;
  this.age = y;
  this.test = "Test 1";
}
// Following properties will ALSO be inherited
Human.prototype.citizen = "USA";
Human.prototype.employer = "Google";
Human.prototype.test = "Test 2";

function Male(x, y) {
  // Following properties will be the own properties of Male instances
  this.name = x;
  this.age = y;
  this.gender = "Male";
}

// Inheritance - Connecting Male object with Human object
Male.prototype = new Human(); // no arguments are passed
Male.prototype.constructor = Male; // correcting constructor property

var albert = new Male("Albert", 25);
```

Then, i want to do some testing on the code

```
Human.isPrototypeOf(albert); // I expect it to return TRUE
```

**But it return FALSE, why is that?**

and, for the following test

```
Human.hasOwnProperty("age"); // /i expect it to return TRUE
```

**But it return FALSE, why is that?**

Thanks,

**Edit**
My questions are slightly different with the other question since it's also talk about prototype chain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [isPrototypeOf in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890392/isprototypeof-in-javascript)

Comment: Try to keep one question per question, but you never define any `Human.age`, so false is expected (you are setting `.age` on your `Human` instances though).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Human` function *isn't* in `albert`'s prototype chain. The object referenced by `Human.prototype` is:

```
Human.prototype.isPrototypeOf(albert); // true
```

> Human.hasOwnProperty("age"); // /i expect it to return TRUE

The `Human` function doesn't have an `age` property. Instances created with it by `new` do:

```
new Human().hasOwnProperty("age"); // true
```

---

Side note: The way you're setting up the inheritance chain is common and shown in a lot of examples, but incorrect in two ways:

1. You don't want to use `new Human` to create `Male.prototype`.
2. You *do* want to call `Human` from `Male`:

So:

```
function Male(x, y) {
    // Give Human its chance to initialize the object (#2)
    Human.call(this, x, y);
    // ...
}

// Don't use new Human to create the prototype (#1)
Male.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype);
Male.prototype.constructor = Male;
```

The reason you don't use `new Human` to create the prototype for `Male` is simple: `Human` expects arguments, but you don't have any to give it.

Here's an updated ES5 and earlier version of that code:

```js
function Human(name, age) { // Argument names should be meaningful
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.test = "Test 1";
}

Human.prototype.citizen = "USA";
Human.prototype.employer = "Google";
Human.prototype.test = "Test 2";

function Male(name, age) {
  Human.call(this, name, age);
  this.gender = "Male";
}

Male.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype);
Male.prototype.constructor = Male;

var albert = new Male("Albert", 25);
console.log(Human.prototype.isPrototypeOf(albert)); // true
console.log(new Human().hasOwnProperty("age"));     // true
```

Or of course, use ES2015+ (transpiling if your target doesn't support it yet):

```js
// THIS SNIPPET REQUIRES A BROWSER WITH ES2015+ SUPPORT

class Human {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.test = "Test 1";
  }
}

Human.prototype.citizen = "USA";
Human.prototype.employer = "Google";
Human.prototype.test = "Test 2";

class Male extends Human {
  constructor(name, age) {
    super(name, age);
    this.gender = "Male";
  }
}

let albert = new Male("Albert", 25);
console.log(Human.prototype.isPrototypeOf(albert)); // true
console.log(new Human().hasOwnProperty("age"));     // true
```

---

You've said you're trying to see how the chain works. Here's a diagram of what we have in memory after creating `albert` (with several details removed for simplicity):

```
         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
         |                                                                      |
         \ +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                                                   |
Human−−−−−>|    function    |                                                   |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                            +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
           | prototype      |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>|       object       | |    
           | name: "Human"  |                          / +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |    
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                          | | constructor        |−+
                                                       | | citizen: "USA"     |
         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ | | employer: "Google" |
         |                                           | | | test: "Test 2"     |
         \ +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                        | | +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
Male−−−−−−>|    function    |                        | |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ | |
           | prototype      |−−−>|     object      | | |
           | name: "Male"   |  / +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ | |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | | constructor     |−+ |
                               | | [[Prototype]]   |−−−+
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
albert−−−−>|     object     |  |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
           | name: "Albert" |  |
           | age: 25        |  |
           | gender: "Male" |  |
           | [[Prototype]]  |−−+
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

`[[Prototype]]` above is the name the spec uses for the "internal slot" of an object that contains its reference to its prototype object. In contrast, `prototype`, the property on functions (e.g., `Human.prototype`), is just a normal property of functions that points to the object that `new` will use as the `[[Prototype]]` of the new object it creates if you use that function with `new`.

Some notes on that diagram:

- All functions have a `[[Prototype]]` internal slot that points to the object `Function.prototype` points to (omitted above for simplicity).
- `Human`, the function, has a `name` property: `"Human"`
- `Male`, the function, has a `name` property: `"Male"`
- The object `albert` refers to has a `name` property: `"Albert"`
- `albert`'s `[[Prototype]]` is `Male.prototype`; `Male.prototype`'s `[[Prototype]]` is `Human.prototype` (and `Human.prototype`'s `[[Prototype]]`, not shown, is `Object.prototype).

In a comment you've said:

> I just can't understand why after inheritance statement we can do `Male.prototype.isPrototypeOf(albert)` return `true` but not in `Human.isPrototypeOf(albert)` (it return `false`) since `Male.prototype` is an instance of `Human`

Because `Human`, the function, is nowhere in `albert`'s prototype chain. Lets' look at `albert`'s prototype chain:

- `albert`'s `[[Prototype]]` is `Male.prototype`
- `Male.prototype`'s `[[Prototype]]` is `Human.prototype`
- `Human.prototype`'s `[[Prototype]]` is `Object.prototype`
- `Object.prototype`'s `[[Prototype]]` is `null`

As a diagram:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
|    albert     |    | Male.prototype |    | Human.prototype |    |  Object.prototype   |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
| [[Prototype]] |−−−>| [[Prototype]]  |−−−>| [[Prototype]]   |−−−>| [[Prototype]]: null |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

So `Human`, the function, is nowhere in that chain.

Comment: For 2nd question, if `Human.hasOwnProperty("age")` doesn't work since it's not an instance, why did `Male.hasOwnProperty("name")` will return `true` and `Male.hasOwnProperty("age")` will return `false` ?

Comment: @xcode: Because as of ES2015 (aka "ES6"), functions have a `name` property. If you looked at `Male.name` you'd see it's `"Male"`.

Comment: also for note `Human.hasOwnProperty("name")` will return `true`, so what happen here? I really interested on understanding how this chain work. Thank you

Comment: @xcode: Again, functions have a `name` property. `Human.name` will be `"Human"`.

Comment: @xcode: I'll add a quick diagram, I think it might help.

Comment: in the line `Male.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype);` it means that the prototype of `Male.prototype` will be equal to `Human.prototype`, that means:

if let say: 
`A (an instance) -> prototype of A -> prototype of (prototype of A) -> .... -> Object.prototype -> null`

then:
`albert (instance) -> albert.__proto__ (equal to Male.prototype) -> albert.__proto__.__proto__ (equal to Human.prototype) -> Object.prototype -> null` shouldn't it be like that?

Comment: I just can't understand why after inheritance statement we can do `Male.prototype.isPrototypeOf(albert)` return `true` but not in  `Human.isPrototypeOf(albert)`(it return `false`) since `Male.prototype` is an instance of `Human`

Comment: @xcode: *"in the line Male.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype); it means that the prototype of Male.prototype will be equal to Human.prototype,"* No, it doesn't mean that. It means `Male.prototype` is an object that inherits from `Human.prototype`.

Comment: @xcode: I've updated again to show a diagram of just `albert`'s prototype chain to demonstrate why `Human` isn't anywhere in it.

Comment: 1 hell of an answer!